# Like it button not very friendly

Tags: 2013

IN sp 2013, the only way to like a page or document is to add the column to the view, and depending on the type of like, then you will see rating stars or smiles.  But this means the person has to go to a view to be able to like it.

I do know how to create a custom ribbon button, but how can I like a page from the ribbon code?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Cato Auestad](https://coderwall.com/p/urb8kg) has made a quite nice and easy way to this. Copy paste his code into your ribbon command and it should work.

```
EnsureScriptFunc('reputation.js', 'Microsoft.Office.Server.ReputationModel.Reputation', function () {
    Microsoft.Office.Server.ReputationModel.Reputation.setLike(aContextObject, 
        _spPageContextInfo.pageListId.substring(1, 37),  
        _spPageContextInfo.pageItemId, false);

    aContextObject.executeQueryAsync(
        function () {
            // Do something if successful
        }, function (sender, args) {
            // Do something if error
    });
});
```